# Search txt file for title and give value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to read a txt file list from a folder, in this txt file is the report with some tags (name of the test) like the example:

t1.txt

```
Test1 400 Speed;P;188;GELE;0;N;11
Test2 300 Speed;P;200;GELE;0;N;11
Test3 200 Speed;P;201;GELE;0;N;11
Test4 100 Speed;P;188;GELE;0;N;11
```

The value i want to get is the 200 from test2 in this example, this value changes from txt file to another. The title name for the test is always the same, the line number can vary. How do i get a macro that just gives the value in this position

Test2 300 Speed;P;**200**;GELE;0;N;11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite easy: get the correct line with `find` or `findstr` and extract the desired token with a `for /f` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=3 delims=;" %%a in ('findstr /ibc:"test2 " t1.txt') do set "var=%%a"
echo the number is %var%
```

Comment: Thank you. How do i do that for the multiple files inside one folder and not just one txt, and save the result in Results.txt

Comment: `(for /f "tokens=3 delims=;" %%a in ('findstr /ibc:"test2 " *.txt') do echo %%a)>result.out`